# HtmlAgilityPack select only inner text Node

Tags: c#, html, linq

This is my sample html input part of bigger html file.

```cs
string html = "<html> <p>Ingredients:</p> </html>";
```

I want to retrieve only node having inner text **Ingredients**.
 **Ingredients** may come in html node p, div, strong etc.

My c# code to achieve this using HtmlAgility pack and linq is

```cs
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

List<HtmlNode> ingredientList = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where
                        (x => x.InnerText.Contains("Ingredients:")).ToList();
```

Result of this code gives me 3 nodes

```
<html> node
<p> node
#text node
```

I want retrieve only

```
<p> node
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your platform support XPath i.e HtmlAgilityPack's `SelectNodes()` method is available, you can use XPath expression to get element where one of its direct-child text node contains the keyword :

```
List<HtmlNode> ingredientList = doc.DocumentNode
                                   .SelectNodes("//*[text()[contains(.,'Ingredients:')]]")
                                   .ToList();
```